# I can't catch sys.exit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, exit

I want to prevent a python program to quit when it calls `sys.exit`, but the following solution doesn't work:

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import sys
>>> try:
...     sys.exit()
... except SystemExit:
...     print('asd')
...
   
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've also tried `BaseException`, but it quits anyway. It seems like it's not an exception at all.
How is this possible? Is every guide on the argument wrong? It can't be.

Comment: Weird. Cannot reproduce. What happens with bare `except:`?

Comment: the same thing.

Comment: Is there anything unusual about how you're running Python, other than it being in Windows?

Comment: I'm using pycharm. I tried running the file (not the code above in the console) and it seems it works. Still not working in the console thogh, this must be where the problem comes from.

Comment: @carlo: Please describe what you mean by _doesn't work_

Comment: I've tried it in PyCharm and via an interactive session in the console and it worked in both situations (Python 3.8.5)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer it quits

Comment: @Kemp it says "PyDev console", is this relevant maybe?

Comment: I imagine Pycharm might have some special hook into `sys.exit` to make it exit gracefully.

Comment: quite annoying. I couldn't try my code on the console